# What are examples of non-Levi Civita connections (for example on a sphere)?

Tags: smooth-manifolds, connections

Since connections in general do not require that we have a Riemannian manifold, but only a smooth manifold, I find it kind of weird that the only examples of connections that I find in the internet are those which use the Levi-Civita connection.
So, I wanted to know of any examples of non-Levi-Civita connections.
If somebody could also give an example of an easily-visualizable parallel transport (like on $S^2$) using that connection it would be great.

Comment: You simply have to look for an example of a non torsion free connection. See e.g. this answer (https://mathoverflow.net/a/20510/45845) in a related post defining a connection which is not the Levi-Civita.

Comment: @Test123 In the example you give then, it seems to me that with a torsion-full connection we "lose" what we intuitively call parallel. Is my understanding wrong? I mean, in that example we have a vector that is doing circles around its travelling axis. So, how can that ever be interpreted as parallel? Of course, I could drive a car with a weird seat that let me rotate like that and then I could view the parallel transported vector as being the same at each instance of time(with respect to me it would not change). Is this what is meant as parallel transport using a torsion-full connection?

Comment: It reminds me of a non-inertial reference frame that is rotating around itself and also travelling at a particular direction.

Comment: N.B. the geodesics of the connection on $\Bbb R^3$ in the example Kal cited are just those of the standard connection---i.e., the straight lines. But there are also connections whose (unparameterized) geodesics are not the geodesics of any Levi-Civita connection, i.e., of any metric.